# Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices 2014 by 2014. Matrix $A$ is invertible. Is this equation possible: $AB-BA=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem: Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices 2014 by 2014. Matrix $A$ is invertible. Is this equation possible: $AB-BA=A$? Explain your answer.**

I was studying for exams and I found this problem. Since it says that matrix $A$ is invertible I tried multiplying it with $A^{-1}$ or assuming $A$ is orthogonal but, sadly, I see no connection.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, after multiplying by $A^{-1}$, $$B-A^{-1}BA = I_{2014}$$Now take the trace of each side to obtain a contradiction.